# What is the quickest way to convert a React app to React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This may be a naive question, but I couldn't find too much information on this topic. 
I have a fully functional react-redux application and I would now like to port it to iOS and Android. I have no need to use any native features like GPS or Camera etc. In theory I just want to make a sort of webview that runs the existing React app, and then tweak it until it looks more presentable. 
My first attempt was to simply use my current jsbundle file and stick it into the AppDelegate as the jsCodeLocation. That expectably caused all sorts of errors such as "window" not being defined.

I guess my question is: how do people usually manage their native and non-native codebases? Are they completely separate, or is there a way to recycle most of the code?

Answer (score 62):

As others have mentioned there's no quick way to convert react to react-native.

A possible alternative if you want your react app to run on a mobile device without rewriting your codebase is to use Cordova.  For fun I ported a react-web app into a mobile app using Cordova in just a few minutes.  There are some drawbacks to this method, but the benefit is that you can have a working mobile app in very little time.

Below are the steps if anyone is interested in a Cordova workaround alternative:

REACT SETUP (done in command line)

```
>1. npx create-react-app my-app
>2. cd my-app
>3. npm start
```

DEPLOY TO STATIC:

```
>1. Update your package.json file from your my-app directory to add "homepage":"." (see below)

  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage":".",
  "dependencies": {
```

```
>2. Build (in command line) npm run build
```

CORDOVA INTEGRATION (in command line)

```
>1.  cd ../ (change to wherever you want the project created, don't do this inside your existing react app folder)
>2.  npm install -g cordova (only if you already don't have Cordova installed)
>3.  cordova create MyApp 
>4.  cd MyApp
>5.  cordova platform add ios //or android or browser
```

ADD A COUPLE STEPS FOR INCLUDING YOUR REACT PROJECT

```
>1. Open your Cordova MyApp www folder, delete all files and folders in it except for the 'js' folder
>2. Back in your react build folder update the index file to add two cordova scripts:
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

```
>3. copy all your files from the react build folder into the Cordova www folder (replacing everything except the js folder)
```

BUILD REACT-CORDOVA APP (in command line, inside your Cordova project)

```
>1. cordova build ios //or android or browser
```

TEST OR DEPLOY TO STORE ETC.

```
>1. Use xcode to open open your react-cordova .xcodeproject, this can be found in the MyApp/Platforms/ios/
>2. Select your simulator and run.  Enjoy your new mobile app!
```

TWEAK
There are some minor tweaks you'll need to do (like remove the tap delay...etc) 
-I think this is why people think Cordova apps are slow, but it's an easy fix...

Comment: What are the drawbacks that you mentioned from this approach? I'd like to understand the pros and cons more clearly before I go down this route

Comment: When I run "cordova build android", I got this error.

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio.

Comment: The most significant drawback is that it's against the iOS terms of service to deploy a wrapped web app to the App Store. It will likely be caught by the submission review process and you will not be able to publish your app. See Guideline 4.2 - Design - Minimum Functionality. Your mobile app must be "... sufficiently different from a mobile browsing experience"

Answer (score 33):

You cannot just use your whole code into the react native application. First and foremost, you have to follow the react native architecture and then develop your UI using react native components.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
You'll get most of the help here.

There is another option also, you can just create a new react-native project and use webview in it and display your whole website there.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview

Comment: The last link shows Page not found.

Comment: @ShadmanFatin just updated the link.

Answer (score 28):

Some of the reusable things are `styles`:

```
var style = {
     box: {height: 30, width: 30, padding: 10, ect...}
}
```

`Logic` such as state :

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);

 this.state= {text: "hi"};
}
```

the state can be shared between navite and dom like so

```
<View>
<Text>this.state.text</Text>
</View>
```

dom looks like this

```
<div>this.state.text</div>
```

You can even share functions but you have to be careful like it was stated above, as long as you're not directly invoking any dom or refs in your logic.

```
onClick(){
 this.setState({text: "good bye"});
}
```

Comment: This was exactly the answer I was looking for.  I think it does a good job of getting to the crux of the matter - not the mechanical "how", but the theoretical "how".  How can you design application components that are suitable for both web and mobile?

Answer (score 16):

They're usually pretty separate, partly because your render target is different (i.e. no `div`s) and partly because of things like `window` not being available. It's possible to reuse code between web and native apps, but only if you're very careful about it.

From the [react native release blog post](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/26/introducing-react-native.html):

> It's worth noting that we're not chasing “write once, run anywhere.” Different platforms have different looks, feels, and capabilities, and as such, we should still be developing discrete apps for each platform

Answer (score 15):

WebViews and React-native are two completely separate concepts. Either you want to go with the former (than you can actually use your application without much hassle), or with the latter. In that case, you could probably re-use some of the business logic, however most of the rendering would have to be rewritten.

React native is `learn once, write anywhere`, not `learn once, write once` :)

Answer (score 6):

For those who searching for a way to code once with `react-native` and export for **Web**, **Android**, and **IOS**, I suggest [Expo](https://expo.dev/).
It suggests building for the web just with this command `expo build:web`.
 [Here is the full document](https://docs.expo.dev/distribution/publishing-websites/#creating-a-build)

And about `Webview` that you have mentioned, I had made projects for **Web** and then use `Webview` to make mobile application of them, but it should be fully responsive and [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) to act as a real application when navigating between pages.
My own examples are: 
 Web: [hoobi.ir](https://hoobi.ir/home_design) Android: [Home Design App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mehrg.homedesign) 
And another example is [vitrinom](https://vitrinom.ir/)

Comment: This uses the excellent [react-native-web package](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web), which also works well on its own to build a truly cross platform app in react-native.

Answer (score 4):

Updating an answer for 2022: Ionic (although this tech came about in [2013])(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_(mobile_app_framework))

You can use [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/)!
I am planning on using it for a few of my bootstrapped projects where I would like to prove concept first before doing a full on Native build.

Some **pros** of Ionic:

- Support for React, Angular, Vue
- fast to build and deploy to both iOS and Android
- can be built using browser based technologies i.e. traditional React development
- JS is all you need (I suppose HTML, CSS, etc too)
- plugins for mobile device features such as camera, fingerprint, NFC, geoloc, push notifications, deep links, etc

**Cons**:

- Debugging is hard
- Error messages are vague, which makes Debugging harder
- You need to go through the app on your device in order to debug device specific issues. But this would be necessary for native builds anyways.
- Sometimes builds just crash!

My advice with technologies such as Ionic and Cordova (mentioned by @Paul Schorey) is tread with caution when using these tools live for real users. It is probably best to have plans to go native as soon as you are able to, have the resources, or have the users that necessitates migration.

Answer (score -2):

You have to refer the react native structure to actually understand how to convert your react app to your react native app.

To start from scratch I would suggest: https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.