# How to port my react code into a mobile app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React Noobie here. I'm having a problem in converting my React Application into an app, either chrome, ios, or android. My code works perfectly on the web browser (I happen to use Material UI which cause a hell lots of trouble). So I am looking for any fast, easy way to turn it into an application that can run.

If there's a way to turn a web application into an app locally.

Thank You So MUCH in advance!!!

Comment: Hi , maybe you can [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463547/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-convert-a-react-app-to-react-native/35470443)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... Do you really need react-native? My suggestion is to pack your application into cordova and use it there. [Some info about that](https://medium.com/@pshubham/using-react-with-cordova-f235de698cc3)

Comment: Thanks! Will definitely look into it!

Answer (score 1):

React native is different from React.js. for example in react you have "div" in react native you have "View" and it's a native view.
you should rewrite your app with react native. and you can use the same code for web as well with the help of react native web.

but you have other options as well you can convert your app to ***PWA*** or a hybrid app