# how to convert react.js web app to react native mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, web

I have a react.js web app I need to convert to the mobile app, Is there any way to do that? 
I have tried to search for a solution but I did not find anything that can help
Thanks.

Comment: No tools are available to convert reactjs app to react native mobile app. You have to convert each component manually. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463547/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-convert-a-react-app-to-react-native

Comment: Have your read this medium article: https://medium.com/@gwen_faraday/converting-a-react-app-to-react-native-d7df17968fc6

Comment: Only web view must be helpfull