# Convert react js to React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, web-applications, mobile-application

I have a react js web application project. I need to develop the same project as mobile application.

Can i convert my reactjs web application project to react-native mobile application project?

If it is yes, How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

no you can't convert. you need rebuild as you can use logic and most of the code from you react js but a few things you need to update like routing and Jsx etc

Answer (score 0):

There is no quick way of converting a whole React App to React Native, you need to take care of Native components, setup, and configs, for example, in a React App the Entry point is your index.js file, packed by ReactDom, in React Native(or expo) you will need to set up an [AppRegistrty](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appregistry) and probably a Metro bundler.
However, if it's a component you want to transform into a ReactNative component, it's doable, considering these few similarities:

- A `<div />` can be substituted by a `View />` imported from `react-native`
- A `<button />` by `<TouchableOpacity />`
- Put all your texts into `<Text />`
  All imported from `react-native`

#### About styling

None of those React Native components has a `className: string` props, instead  use `style: object` props

#### About navigation

Too many differences here, you have to set up a custom navigation logic helped by [the react native navigation library](https://reactnavigation.org/)

Briefly, you cannot directly translate a react codebase into a react native, however, a single component exporting a JSX element(like a button, a card, ...) can be using those technics I shared
Additionally, [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463547/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-convert-a-react-app-to-react-native) can be a big plus